# Certain documentation pages block, preventing interactions

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

If I try to visit https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2958/alternative-collections the page loads but I often cannot interact with it; the tab shows the loading icon and eventually Chrome prompts me to kill the tab due to a runaway script. Feels like some sort of request is failing and preventing the page load from finishing, but I don't have more data than that.

Windows 10, Chrome 51

Comment: That page loads fine for me (Win 10, Chrome 51). Do you happen to have a draft in progress on that topic?

Comment: Probably; I was trying to edit something but I'm not sure what its status is.

Comment: Hm, yeah, that's probably the same issue we have elsewhere as well then. I'm hoping to have a better answer tomorrow, but in the meantime... FWIW, Firefox will probably gracefully offer to either keep running the script or kill it in the meantime without bringing the browser to its knees like Chrome does.

Comment: I've had similar problems on bigger items with Chrome (51.0.2704.103 — update in progress; 52.0.2743.82 now installed) on Mac OS X 10.11.6, and also with Firefox (47.0.1).  I mentioned it in chat late last night (US/Pacific time).  I've restarted the browsers and still run into problems.  I'm not sure whether a slower internet connection is an issue — it sometimes seemed to be hanging on other sites.

Comment: I've hit this too and what's weird is, it doesn't happen consistently. It's been driving me nuts trying to figure out even what to report. I'm glad someone was able to (1) make it happen and (2) get back to where they were in order to report it (total browser meltdown when I hit it, Latest Chrome on a Macbook Pro 2015)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but it's too long for a comment and I didn't want to post a duplicate question.  (Apologies for the breach of protocol)

I have a draft exhibiting this issue consistently.  This won't be of any interest to anyone but developers, since it's *my* draft, but if you have a way of accessing users' drafts, pull up mine to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/2063/overloading/1113/magic-methods#) documentation topic.

- In chrome, the "tab stopped responding" notification appears.
- In edge, it sort of just lags out.
- In firefox, it says the script has stopped responding:

The script is minified, so I'm not sure how much help I can be, but the file causing issues is `docs-transpiled.en.js` and function is: `StackExchange.docs.diff` and it's somewhere in the 32062 character long line 1.

Answer (score 0):

We made some improvements to how drafts are a loaded. In particular, we no longer do character diffs and diff on words instead. We also fixed an issue where the same diffs would re-run multiple times during opening of a draft.

This made things ... better. Not perfect still, since some diffs just take a while to run no matter what. We have a couple ideas for improvement there as well, but the immediate "oh god this page takes 15 minutes to load" stuff has been mitigated a good deal.